# How to use animate css to display random compliments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**JS:**

```
function randComp() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * compliments.length) + 1) - 1;
};

function generateCompliment() {
    var rand = randComp();
    return compliments[rand]
};

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').html(generateCompliment());
  $('h1').addClass('animated slideInLeft');

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
     <h1>Compliment Generator</h1><br/>
     <button class="btn btn-default">Another one!</button>
</div>
```

Compliments is just an array of strings.
When the button is clicked, a random compliment slides in from the left, then the next time it's clicked, the `<h1>` just disappears. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the problem

Comment: You are adding the `animated` class on the first click, the second time you click it, it will already be there so will not animate again. In your click event, remove the `animated` class before you generate a new compliment.

Answer (score 2):

Before add a css class `'animated slideInLeft'` remove the same class is exist

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $('h1').removeClass('animated slideInLeft');
  $('h1').html(generateCompliment());
  $('h1').addClass('animated slideInLeft');

});
```

Hope this work :)